# Get Image name onclick

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am new to Spring boot and thymeleaf.
I wanted to know how I could get the name or id of an image onclick.
Any help or documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried already? Please share what code you have which shows you have made an attempt to solve this issue yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try this one:

```
th:attr="onclick=|what you want to do|"
```

or you can use use the  tag inside th:each:

```
<img th:src="@{'/photos/' + ${yourimage.image}}"/>
```

depending on what you want to do.

And as long as you asked for documentation, check this out about attributes:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes

Comment: Thank you i will see what i can do with what u suggested and look at the documentation.Thanks again